# Materialize Model looks different When class is used instead of id

Tags: css, materialize

I'm using Materialize framework for my website. In `materializecss.com/Modal.html` they have given `id` like `<div id='cart_modal' class="modal modal-fixed-footer">` but I want to give class `<div class="cart_modal modal modal-fixed-footer">`

Problem is that When I used class it adds `z-index: 1003;` to `div`.

**Modal Code**

```
<div class="cart_modal modal modal-fixed-footer">
   <div class="modal-content">
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <a data="<?php echo $value->product_id; ?>" class="indigo-text modal-action modal-close waves-effect btn-flat ">Add To Cart</a>
      <a class="indigo-text modal-action modal-close waves-effect btn-flat ">Cancel</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Modal Trigger**

```
$('.cart_modal').openModal();
```

I have created jsfiddle of both but They works perfectly.

`jsfiddle` - [id](https://jsfiddle.net/Tirth_Patel/73znbv3k/3/)
`jsfiddle` - [class](https://jsfiddle.net/Tirth_Patel/va1nkhwL/)

**Images**

When `id` attribute is used,

[image]

[image]

When `class` attribute is used,

[image]

[image]

Comment: it creates `z-index:1003` both id and class, thats not a materialize CSS issue, but most likely a CSS conflict with your own CSS

Comment: But in second image (id is used) It doesn't show `z-index: 1003;`.

Comment: Well i checked your fiddle and it does have

Comment: Do you have multiple modals with that same class? Maybe you are opening many modals at once causing this to happen.